# ymaps3 (Яндекс.Карты API 3.0) Редактор геометрии

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi, карты, яндекс-карта-api, яндекс-карты

Существует ли редактор геометрии для **ymaps3** (Яндекс.Карты API 3.0).
Создание/редактирование точек, полигонов, линий (?).

В документации ничего не нашёл. Ничего похожего на editor (из версии 2.1) внутри YMapFeature нет.
В типах (@yandex/ymaps3-types) нашёл `YMapFeatureEditor`, но что это такое и как его использовать ни гугл, ни яндекс ничего не говорят.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, пока такого редактора нет. И когда появится, неизвестно.
Ответ из службы поддержки Яндекса:

"Здравствуйте!

Пришло уточнение по вашему вопросу.

На данный момент визуального редактора геометрии в JS API 3.0 нет. Но вы можете следить за нашими обновлениями в клубе разработчиков.

Обращайтесь, если понадобится помощь или возникнут вопросы!"